# apply prepends space for logical

Tags: r, space, chr

Having a strange issue here with apply and R 3.0.1.

I have a huge dataframe with text, numbers and logical values.
The logical values are converted to chr when I use apply, but because
R allows something like TRUE == "TRUE" that isn't a problem.

But to some logical values, apply seems to prepend a space, and TRUE == " TRUE" returns NA. Of course, I could do

```
sapply(cuelist[,4],FUN=function(logicalvalue) as.logical(sub("^ +", "", logicalvalue)))
```

but that isn't nice and I still don't know why R does that.

```
df <- data.frame(test=c("a","b","<",">"),logi=c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))
apply(df, MARGIN=1, function(listelement) print(listelement) )
```

Interestlingly, the spaces only appear in this example on [2,1] and [2,4]

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          0.1
>   year           2013
>   month          05
>   day            16
>   svn rev        62743
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
>   nickname       Good Sport

Edit: same behaviour on R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)

Edit2: My dataframe lools like this

```
> df
  test  logi
1    a FALSE
2    b FALSE
3    <  TRUE
4    >  TRUE

> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ test: Factor w/ 4 levels "<",">","a","b": 3 4 1 2
 $ logi: logi  FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Comments don't allow codes. One moment please.

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(df, quote = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a way, the problem is with `apply`, but more appropriately, the problem is with `as.matrix`, and how it is handling `logical` values.

Here are a few examples to help elaborate on the query I had for Karl.

First, let's create four `data.frame`s to do some tests on.

1. Your original `data.frame` to demonstrate the behavior:
2. A `data.frame` with varying number of characters in the "test" column to look into Karl's explanation of what's going on.
3. A `data.frame` with some numbers to help us start to understand what actually seems to be going on.
4. A `data.frame` where your "logi" column is explicitly created `as.character`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(test = c("a","b","<",">"),
                  logi = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(test = c("aa","b","<",">>"), 
                  logi = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))
df3 <- data.frame(test = c("aa","b","<",">>"), 
                  logi = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
                  num = c(1, 12, 123, 2))
df4 <- data.frame(test = c("aa","b","<",">>"), 
                  logi = as.character(c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)))
```

Now, let's use `as.matrix` on each of them.

This has a space before `TRUE`.

```
as.matrix(df1)
#      test logi   
# [1,] "a"  " TRUE"
# [2,] "b"  "FALSE"
# [3,] "<"  "FALSE"
# [4,] ">"  " TRUE"
```

This has a space before `TRUE`, but the "test" column remains unaffected. Hmm.

```
as.matrix(df2)
#      test logi   
# [1,] "aa" " TRUE"
# [2,] "b"  "FALSE"
# [3,] "<"  "FALSE"
# [4,] ">>" " TRUE"
```

Ahh... This has a space before `TRUE` *and* spaces before shorter numbers. So it seems that perhaps R is considering the numeric underlying value of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, but calculating the width of the number of characters in `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Again, the first "test" column remains unaffected.

```
as.matrix(df3)
#      test logi    num  
# [1,] "aa" " TRUE" "  1"
# [2,] "b"  "FALSE" " 12"
# [3,] "<"  "FALSE" "123"
# [4,] ">>" " TRUE" "  2"
```

Things seem fine here, if you tell R that the `logi` column is a character column.

```
as.matrix(df4)
#      test logi   
# [1,] "aa" "TRUE" 
# [2,] "b"  "FALSE"
# [3,] "<"  "FALSE"
# [4,] ">>" "TRUE"
```

For what it's worth, `sapply` doesn't seem to have that problem.

```
sapply(df1, as.matrix)
#      test logi   
# [1,] "a"  "TRUE" 
# [2,] "b"  "FALSE"
# [3,] "<"  "FALSE"
# [4,] ">"  "TRUE"
```

---

#### Update

In the R Public chat room, Joshua Ulrich points to `format` being the culprit. `as.matrix` uses `as.vector` for factors, which converts them to character (try `str(as.vector(df1$test))` to see what I mean; for everything else, it uses `format`, but unfortunately, doesn't have an option to include any of the arguments from `format`, one of which is `trim` (which is by default set to `FALSE`).

Compare the following:

```
A <- c(TRUE, FALSE)

format(A)
# [1] " TRUE" "FALSE"
format(A, trim = TRUE)
# [1] "TRUE"  "FALSE"
format(as.character(A))
# [1] "TRUE " "FALSE"
format(as.factor(A))
# [1] "TRUE " "FALSE"
```

---

So, how to sort of easily convert logical columns to character? Maybe something like this (though I would suggest creating a backup of your data first):

```
df1[sapply(df1, is.logical)] <- lapply(df1[sapply(df1, is.logical)], as.character)
df1
#   test  logi
# 1    a  TRUE
# 2    b FALSE
# 3    < FALSE
# 4    >  TRUE
as.matrix(df1)
#      test logi   
# [1,] "a"  "TRUE" 
# [2,] "b"  "FALSE"
# [3,] "<"  "FALSE"
# [4,] ">"  "TRUE"
```

Comment: This is very nice! With that I can pre-edit the dataframe before it is handled by apply/parApply. Still, I don't think this is appropiate behaviour for a dataframe in combination with apply functions. Maybe this really is bug-territory? Should I or someone post that to the R-bugtracker? Maybe I'm not experienced enough with R to realize the "positive" or "useful" underlying concept of this.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your effort, very analytical :) I changed my whole codebase now, so that all logical lists given are strings in the first place. Doesn't feel comfortable or right, but it works. I don't have to slow down my calculating processes by trimming each and every logical column I have.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely due to apply, that converts the data frame to a matrix, so all elements have the same type, here character, and logicals are converted to it.
TRUE gets converted to " TRUE" to match the number of characters of "FALSE":

```
"FALSE"
" TRUE"
```

To get convinced:

```
as.matrix(df)
```

Instead you could use the a*ply from plyr package, e.g.

```
a_ply(df, 1, print)
```

Comment: Ah I understand now. @AnandaMahto was right,     print(df, quote = TRUE) really adds the spaces, too, but I was still able to do     df[1,1]==TRUE. Is there another way than plyr? I need the parapply for the parallel package, which has the same behaviour.

Comment: Did you actually test this with some other examples? I don't think this answer is quite right.

Comment: Try your explanation on `df1 <- data.frame(test=c("a","bb","<<",">"),logi=c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE))`. Why doesn't the first column get extra spaces?

Comment: Yes, that is right, but your still able to do something like df1[3,2]==TRUE , while this doesn't work in the apply function.

Comment: plyr also offers parallelization with the .parallel option

Comment: If you really want, you still can use lapply:   res <- lapply(seq_along(df), function(ci) {
    row <- df[ci, ]
    lapply(row, print)
  })

Comment: @KarlForner, I've [tried to elaborate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18619447/1270695) on what I was observing. This feels somewhat like bug territory to me though. I understand what is happening with numeric when character conversion occurs, but not why it also applies the way it does to logical.